# How to output the conents of a wx.ListView box to an external log file

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wx.ListView box named lvActions that I add data to using code similar to

```
self.lvActions.Append([datetime.datetime.now(),filename,"Moved"])
```

What I want to do is when I am all done with my actions and have a list, I want to output the full contents of this file to a logfile.  This is how I tried to do it

```
logfile = open(logFullPath, "a")
for events in self.lvActions:
    logfile.write(events)
logfile.close()
```

The error I get back is

```
TypeError: 'ListView' object is not iterable
```

If a ListView is not iterable, how can I dump its contents to a file?

Comment: Does the list have only one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have pointed out, the listview itself is not iterable in the way that you'd like.  As with most of the wx widgets, you need to get a count of the items in the widget and then ask for the text of the item at that location.  Since you are working with a listview (which is derived from listctrl), you will have to get the text for each column individually

```
logfile = open(logFullPath, "a")
for event in xrange(self.lvActions.GetItemCount()):
    date = self.lvActions.GetItem(event, 0).GetText()        # item in column 0
    filename = self.lvActions.GetItem(event, 1).GetText()    # col 1, etc
    action = self.lvActions.GetItem(event, 2).GetText()
    logfile.write( "{0}, {1}, {2}\n".format(date, filename, action)

logfile.close()
```

GetItem() returns a ListItem object that represents the data in that row/column.  I then use the GetText() method to get the text from that item object.  You should probably also add error as appropriate.  Also, I have used hard coded column names (based on your input).  You'll need to adjust those as appropriate.

Comment: You could avoid the need for `logfile.close()` and some exception handling if you put this inside a `with` block: `with open(logFullPath, "a") as logfile:`